# How do I force a task to run on the UI thread?

Tags: c#, windows-8, task

Original message below. Let me try and explain with more details why I am asking for this.

I have a page that listens to the Share charm request:

```
void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    m_transferManager = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
    m_transferManager.DataRequested += TransferManager_DataRequested;
}
```

When the event fires (`TransferManager_DataRequested`) it does not fire on the UI thread:

```
void TransferManager_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    var data = args.Request.Data;
          // More related stuff omitted - not important.
    data.SetDataProvider(StandardDataFormats.Bitmap, GetImage_DelayRenderer);
}
```

Now, when `GetImage_DelayRender` is called, it also does not get called on the UI thread. However, in it, I need to do a bunch of UI related things. Specifically, I need to call a method that only works on the UI (it's a method I use elsewhere and I want to reuse it's logic). The method is called `GetImageAsync` and it needs to run on the UI because it does a bunch of interactions with WriteableBitmap. It also does a bunch of async operations (such as writing to stream etc) which is why it's async. I block the UI on `GetImageAsync()` for as short a time as I can.

Here's what `GetImage_DelayRender` looks like:

```
private async void GetImage_DelayRenderer(DataProviderRequest request)
{
    var deferral = request.GetDeferral();
    await Dispatcher.RunTask(async () => // RunTask() is an extension method - described in the original question below.
        {
            try
            {
                var bitmapStream = await GetImageAsync();
                request.SetData(RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(bitmapStream));
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        });

    deferral.Complete();
}
```

What I want to know is, what is the most correct way to achieve the call to `Dispatcher.RunTask()` above (which is my hack extension method).

----- START ORIGINAL MESSAGE -------

Say I have the following task:

```
private async Task SomeTask()
{
   await Task.Delay(1000);
   // Do some UI and other stuff that may also be async
}
```

**Edit (Clarification): I do not want to block the UI. The task I want to execute (even in the example, if you read it) WILL NOT block the UI. I just want the task to run in the context of the UI for it's synchronous portions.**

I want to run this on code on the UI thread as an Async operation. Dispatcher.RunXXX() methods take an action, which means they will run the action and notify you when they are done. That's not good enough. I need the entire task to run on the UI thread (as it would have executed had I run it from the UI thread) and then, when done, to notify me back.

The only way I could think of, is to use the Dispatcher.RunXXX() methods to execute an anon delegate that sets a local variable in my method to the task and then awaits that...

```
public async static Task RunTask(this CoreDispatcher dispatcher, Func<Task> taskGiver)
{
    Task task = null;
    await dispatcher.RunAsync(() => task = taskGiver());
    await task;
}
```

This looks pretty damn ugly. Is there a better way of doing it?

Edit2: Guys - read this code - if I execute the first code block above using the RunTask() hack I have, IT WILL NOT BLOCK THE UI on the Task.Delay()...

Comment: Why do you want to run it on the UI thread? it is kind of going against the usage of the Task.

Comment: Can you not use Task and just call a normal method.

Comment: I have the same requirement, but the task performs some work, then at the end of the task I need to update the UI, which can only be done on the UI thread. I think it's a reasonable question. It's the equivalent of PostMessage in Win32.

Comment: @MarkIngram: What's typically is done is calling [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) when all work's done and have it update the UI. There's no need to make the UI hang while a task is being executed (IMHO).

Comment: Agreed with @MBen. You're not providing the proper user experience by forcing a Task to run on the main UI thread. If you want the user to "experience" the time it takes to run the task show them a progress bar or something similar, but don't force them to wait for you. User's are fickle creatures.

Comment: @BradChristie executing it in the UI thread would make the UI hang while the task is being executed. Therefore defeating the whole point of tasks.

Comment: @MBen: How is this "against the usage of task". You are encouraged to use tasks in the UI - that's exactly what keeps the UI responsive.

Comment: @sylon: No - because I want to know when it's done and since it's not a synchronous call (which Action and Func are), it's impossible to do it using this mechanism.

Comment: @MrFox: I agree 100% with you; that's why I mentioned that it should be executed outside the UI thread then (when updates to the UI are necessary) to `.Invoke` the changes.

Comment: @ShaharPrish yes, but normaly Task are run on a different thread. I believe what you are looking for it to update the UI when the Task is done, then you can use the SynchronizationContext to post the results back. Calling the Task on the same Thread as UI, will not make your UI responsive.

Comment: @NominSim: How so? The task will not run synchronously - I am not forcing it to run synchronously. I just want the synchronous part to run in that manner and the rest to run like a normal task initiated from the UI.

Comment: @ShaharPrish: Have you looked at [`TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext.aspx)? I don't fuly believe any realy work should be done on the UI thread, but if you want to...

Comment: @ShaharPrish You don't seem to understand that if you run (or force to run) something from the UI `Thread`, then the UI will **not** be responsive until whatever you're running is done. From your comments it looks like this is not what you want, but rather you want the UI to be responsive, but also to get updated once the method call is complete. To do this you don't want it to run on the UI `Thread`, rather you want to create a `Task` that will update your UI after it completes. (This is why @MBen was saying that you're requesting something against the normal usage of `Task`)

Comment: @MBen: When you, for example, hook an event, and mark it as async and start awaiting tasks, your UI blocks only for the synchronous portions of that code - usually the pieces of code that update the UI or do other very cheap things. Everything that's awaited on is not blocking. All I want is to be able to run a method in such a way when my originating caller is not on the UI thread.

Comment: @NominSim: Thanks for the comment. When you have a method that's marked as async (using the await keyword inside it) and that method is executed, all the code that's not awaited will actually block the UI thread. All the calls that are awaited will actually run on a separate thread and not block the UI. I am assuming we agree on this. *All* I want is for a task (or a method marked as returning a task rather) is to run as if it was fired as an event on the UI thread. That's it.

Comment: @ShaharPrish we might need more info to help you, I don't what you are trying to achieve. When you say away something. the methode containing this return to its caller (Yes of course the continuation doesn't run until later. I feel you just need a Task, you don't have to wait for it. Start it, and add a continuation to it, to update the UI when it is done.

Comment: @MBen: Updated the question with the actual code I am looking at to further explain what it is I am looking for. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

> I want to run this on code on the UI thread as an Async operation.

Then just run it:

```
async void MyEventHandler(object sender, ...)
{
  await SomeTask();
}
```

**Update:**

I'm not sure this is a "legal" operation, but you can schedule that method to run on the UI thread by capturing the `CoreDispatcher` while the UI is active and later calling [`RunAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync.aspx):

```
private async void GetImage_DelayRenderer(DataProviderRequest request)
{
  var deferral = request.GetDeferral();
  Task task = null;
  await coreDispatcher.RunAsync(() => { task = SomeTask(); });
  await task;
  deferral.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Exactly, just make a method in the UI and call it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, I don't see how this solves my problem. I have a general method I want to run - it's not an event - it's not part of a UI element (page, control etc). it's a utility function that happens to be asynchronous. I want to make sure it executes on a UI thread.

Comment: Something has to trigger the "I want this code to run". What triggers it?

Comment: @StephenCleary: The Windows 8 share charm. It triggers it on a non-UI thread.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Thanks - the issue is that RunAsync() will run an Action - it won't run a task. Which means that if you try to run something async, you will not know when the entire call is finished, which is what I want (as I describe in my question).

Comment: @ShaharPrish: I updated the answer with a code example to show what I mean.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Thanks. That's exactly the solution that I found and posted as part of my question. My actual question (and yours in the update) was if there's a more "kosher" way of doing that... :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to do a complete solution, so hopefully you will still find this useful...

First, as others have pointed out, you cannot run something on the UI thread and not have it block the UI thread.  End of discussion.  What you are saying you need is something to run on a non-UI thread and periodically notify the UI thread that there are updates that need to be processed.

To accomplish this, you need something like this...

```
public class LongTask
    {
        public event EventHandler MyEvent;

        public void Execute()
        {
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {

                while (true)
                {
                    // condition met to notify UI
                    if (MyEvent != null)
                        MyEvent(this, null);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

In your UI then, do something like...

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var test = new LongTask();
            test.MyEvent += test_MyEvent;
            test.Execute();
        }

        void test_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                test.Text += " bang ";
            });
```

You could obviously implement this in a much cleaner fashion using something like MVVM, but this is the basic idea.
            }

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't understand how you can say that - obviously when you await tasks on the UI thread (such as you would do from an event that's marked async), the tread will not block while these tasks execute. The solution you present is fine, but it assumes that you have the sync context of the UI to actually start running the operation, which I don't (see my latest edit - at the top of the question). Also pinged you on Lync, but you must have been off by then. In any case - see the clarification I posted with the exact situation I am in fore more info.

Comment: "await task" does not block the UI thread.  Your task is not running on the UI thread while it is executing.  The code you write looks synch, but it does not execute sync.  I think you are confused on how "await task" actually works.  It may look like it blocks because the line of code after await does not execute, but in reality, the UI thread is back processing UI events waiting for a notification from the task that it is done.  It then returns and continues executing the next line of code. The UI thread is never blocked.

Comment: Also, working with classes that do not have access to Dispatcher directly is one of those "known challenges", especially in the MVVM space.  Yes, you will have to pass the Dispatcher if you need it in code that is running on a non-UI thread but needs access to UI bound resources.

Comment: I am not really sure how you can suggest I am saying the UI will be blocked when I say right there in the comment "the tread will not block while these tasks execute". So I am not really sure what you are answering.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it like this:

```
public static Task<string> GetResultAsync()
{
    return Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetResultSync());
}
```

In UI:

```
private async void test()
{

    string result = await GetResultAsync();

    // update UI no problem  
    textbox.Text = result;  

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This will run a single synchronous operation on a non-UI thread. What I want is to run an asynchronous task on the UI thread. This is the mirror image of what I was asking. :)

Comment: This makes no sense to me..if you run an operation on the ui thread you are blocking the ui.

Comment: Not if what I am executing on the UI thread is a task. Look at the code that I posted and tell me if it blocks or not.